# Can't access CustomDocumentProperties in powershell script using Word VBA

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-word

I've got this setting in my `.dotx` template. There are 3 custom properties set on the document. When I try to access these properties in powershell script [using Word VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.customdocumentproperties) (`ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties` property) I can see there are 3 items in the collection, however I can't access the item nor its properties.

[image]

I've tried the following ways:

```sh
Write-Host $Document.CustomDocumentProperties(1) # System.__ComObject
Write-Host $Document.CustomDocumentProperties(1).Name # empty/null

$Document.CustomDocumentProperties | ForEach-Object {
  Write-Host $_  # System.__ComObject
  Write-Host $_.Name   # 3 times empty/null
  Write-Host $_.Value  # 3 times empty/null
  Write-Host $_.Type   # 3 times empty/null
}
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What does $Document | gm reveal?

Comment: I do not use PowerShell so this may be useless to you. Have you looked at this Word MVP pages? https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/DSOFile.htm https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/DSOFile.htm

Comment: @WalterMitty `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass`

Comment: I expected a longer response than that.  Gm usually shows all the members.

Comment: Use the [Scripting Guy's code here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-retrieve-the-custom-properties-of-a-microsoft-word-document/), otherwise good luck :)